# Can this be done in SQL instead of a loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, common-table-expression

I have a couple of tables and would like to update one from the other:

```
create table first_table
(bookstore_id number not null,
event   varchar2(10),
timestamp   date);

create table second_table
(bookstore_id number,
numbooks    number);

insert into second_table values (1,0);
insert into second_table values (2,0);
insert into second_table values (3,0);

insert into first_table values (1, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (1, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (1, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (1, 'REMOVE', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (1, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (1, 'REMOVE', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (2, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (2, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (2, 'REMOVE', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (2, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (2, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (2, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (3, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (3, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (3, 'REMOVE', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (3, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (3, 'REMOVE', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (3, 'ADD', sysdate);
insert into first_table values (3, 'REMOVE', sysdate);
```

The following logic will work to do what I want:

```
begin
    for storeid in (select bookstore_id from second_table)
    loop
        update second_table
        set numbooks =
            (select count(*) from first_table
            where event = 'ADD'
            and bookstore_id = storeid.bookstore_id)
            -   /* actual minus sign is needed here */
            (select count(*) from first_table
            where event = 'REMOVE'
            and bookstore_id = storeid.bookstore_id)
        where bookstore_id = storeid.bookstore_id;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

My question is, can this be done using a single SQL statement, avoiding the loop?

Comment: In *general*, prefer *not* to store data that can be calculated. `second_table` could easily be implemented as a view: `select bookstore_id,SUM(CASE WHEN event='ADD' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) as num_books
 from first_table
 group by bookstore_id`. *if* performance is an issue, there may be ways to have your DBMS persist the data in this view automatically (Oracle: Materialized Views, SQL Server: Indexed Views).

Comment: This is a simplified example of a more complicated problem, but the logic is similar.  My question is whether I can avoid using loops and plsql to do this kind of thing.

Comment: You can avoid loops, this is not difficult to do. But you should definitely listen to the advice and not store data that can trivially be calculated from existing data.

Answer (score 2):

No need for CTE or anything, you can do this:

```
update second_table
set numbooks =
              ((select count(*) from first_table
               where event = 'ADD'
               and bookstore_id = second_table.bookstore_id)
               -   /* actual minus sign is needed here */
               (select count(*) from first_table
                where event = 'REMOVE'
                and bookstore_id = second_table.bookstore_id))
```

It can actually be done with conditional aggregation and avoid 1 of the selects from the first table:

```
update second_table
set numbooks =
              (select (count(CASE WHEN event = 'ADD' then 1 end)
                       -
                       count(CASE WHEN event = 'REMOVE' then 1 end))
               from first_table
               WHERE bookstore_id = second_table.bookstore_id)
 WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from first_table s where second_table.bookstore_id = s.bookstore_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly in SQL.  The following is a method in Oracle (other databases have simpler mechanisms):

```
update second_table st
     set numbooks = (select sum(case when event = 'ADD' then 1
                                     when event = 'REMOVE' then -1
                                     else 0
                                end)
                     from first_table ft
                     where st.bookstore_id = ft.bookstore_id
                    )
     where exists (select 1 from first_table where st.bookstore_id = ft.bookstore_id);
```

Note that the `where` clause only updates rows in the second table that are in the first table.  If you know that all the rows are there -- or if you want missing rows to be updated (with `NULL`, which can easily be changed to a `0`) -- then don't include it.

If there are many rows other types of event, then `where event in ('ADD', 'REMOVE')` in the subquery might benefit performance.